# JavaEE does not throw SQLException when primary key is duplicated

Tags: java, web, tomcat8, java-ee-7, sqlexception

I am studying on a Java Web Application with JavaEE (not SPRING). But I have ran into a problem that my application doesn't throw `SQLException` when a row is inserted into table with **duplicated primary key**.

In details, I have a DAO class `AccountInfoDAO.java` with a `createNewAccount` method:

```
public boolean createNewAccount(String username, String password, 
                                String fullName, boolean role) 
    throws NamingException, SQLException {
    boolean result = false;
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    int iCount = 0;
    
    try {
        con = DBHelpers.makeConnection();
        if (con != null) {
            
            String queryStr = "INSERT INTO "
                    + "accountInfo(username, password, lastname, isAdmin) "
                    + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
            
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(queryStr);
            stmt.setString(1, username);
            stmt.setString(2, password);
            stmt.setNString(3, fullName);
            stmt.setBoolean(4, role);
            
            iCount = stmt.executeUpdate();
            
            if (iCount > 0) {
                result = true;
            }
        } // EndIf Connected
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }
        if (con != null) {
            con.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And my functional Servlet `CreateNewAccountServlet.java` with the `processRequest` method:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    
    String username = request.getParameter("txtUsername");
    String password = request.getParameter("txtPassword");
    String confirm = request.getParameter("txtConfirm");
    String fullname = request.getParameter("txtFullname");
    
    String url = ERROR_PAGE;
    
    AccountInfoCreateError errors = new AccountInfoCreateError();
    boolean foundErr = false;
    
    try {
        // 1. Check valid user input
        if (username.trim().length() < 6 || username.trim().length() > 30) {
            foundErr = true;
            errors.setUsernameLengthErr("Username requires input from 6 to 30 characters!");
        }
        
        if (password.trim().length() < 6 || username.trim().length() > 20) {
            foundErr = true;
            errors.setPasswordLengthErr("Password requires input from 6 to 20 characters!");
        } else if (!password.trim().equals(confirm.trim())) {
            foundErr = true;
            errors.setConfirmNotMatch("Confirm mus be matched with password!");
        }
        
        if (fullname.trim().length() < 2 || fullname.trim().length() > 50) {
            foundErr = true;
            errors.setFullNameLengthErr("Full name requires input from 2 to 50 characters!");
        }
        
        if (foundErr) {
            request.setAttribute("CREATE_ERROR", errors);
        } else {
            // 2. Call DAO
            AccountInfoDAO dao = new AccountInfoDAO();
            boolean result = dao.createNewAccount(username, password, fullname, false);
            if (result) {
                url = LOGIN_PAGE;
            }
        }
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        String errMsg = ex.getMessage();
        log("CreateNewAccountServlet SQL: " + errMsg);
        if (errMsg.contains("Duplicate")) {
            errors.setUsernameIsExisted(username + " is existed");
            request.setAttribute("CREATE_ERROR", errors);
        }
        
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        log("CreateNewAccountServlet Naming: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
        rd.forward(request, response);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

When I run my application, everything works well. A normal new account can be created and inserted into database successfully. But when I try to insert an account with a duplicated username (which is my primary key in the table), it doesn't throw `SQLException`, which is expected to happen. And my TomCat server does not write log, of course.
All of my friends have done this with the exception thrown.
I have tried to re-install my MS SQL Server, try to use different JDBC driver but the result is the same.

I am using JDK 8, NetBeans 8.2 RC, Apache Tomcat 8.0, MS SQL Server 2012 to implement this application.

Hope you can help me to fix this problem!

------- Update
My table design in MS SQL Server
[image: My table design in MS SQL Server]

Comment: Show us the DDL. Asserting you have a primary key, and then showing some DML embedded in Java does not inspire confidence. `fullname` vs `lastname` and `isAdmin` vs `role` (as a `boolean` no less). What I can see makes me nervous.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch hey I just update my table design in my question, if that is what you mean.

Comment: A field named username should be used with a unique constraint. It's not a java problem. Try to insert the doubled row from SQL console and you won't get SQLException too

Comment: @DmitriiBykov I see a “key” icon in the graphic next to `username`. I presume that means a primary key contraint has been assigned, and therefore a unique constraint implicitly?

Comment: Hey @DmitriiBykov, I have run a SQL query in SQL Management Studio: "insert into accountInfo values ('trtranphong', '123456789', 'Phong', 0)" and I recieve a error that: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_accountInfo'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.accountInfo'. The duplicate key value is (trtranphong).
The statement has been terminated."

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the solution. I have to put the `return result;` line out of `finally` block and my application works well! Thanks for your help!